# Passing result from .getJSON() to another function results in undefined

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

Good day everyone,

I am pulling back some data from a database (via a PHP script) using jQuery's .getJSON() method.  This is all well and good, the data comes back just fine and as expected.  The problem occurs when I try to pass the data to a secondary function, no matter how I try to access the values of that data they come back as undefined.  I have a feeling I am overlooking something very simple but after a lot of trial and error I come to SO asking for an extra set of eyes.

Here is a simple example of the JavaScript code.

```
  function fnCheck_Vis(Row, sField, sMode)
  {
    sField = sField+"_vis";
    sTest = Row.sField.val();
    alert(sTest); // Comes back as undefined.
  }

  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("#btnSearch").click(function()
    {
      $("#divResults").empty();
      var ssearch = $("#ssearch").val();
      var i = 0;
      $.getJSON("get_results.php?keywords=" + ssearch,
      function(Data)
      {
        var iRec = 0;
        $.each(Data, function(i, Row)
        {
          fnCheck_Vis(Row, "slinkpic1", "Int");
          var content = Row.slast;
          $("#divResults").append(content);
          iRec++;
        });
        alert(iRec + " records retrieved using AJAX.");            
      });
    });
  });
```

The first piece of the fnCheck_Vis() function works fine and "_vis" is appended to the field name, this is proper behavior.  No matter how I try to access that member in the dataset (Row) I can not get a value back.

I really appreciate any insight that can be given on this issue.

Thanks,

Nicholas

Comment: Have you looked at the data coming back from the server? You can use firebug or the Resources view in Chrome/Safari to see the actual result of your ajax request. What do you see there?

Comment: Do you have an example of the json being returned via your php page?

Comment: sfield is not a property of the JSON object, which is why it is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to access the property of `Row` whose name is stored in `sField`, not its actual `sField` property. Try:

```
function fnCheck_Vis(Row, sField, sMode)
{
    sField = sField + "_vis";
    var sTest = Row[sField];
    alert(sTest);
}
```

Comment: Great catch and you are exactly right that worked like a charm.  Follow-up question: Why does the Row.fieldName convention work in the .each() loop but not after passing to the other function?  Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @Nicholas, do you mean why does `Row.slast` work? That would be because it accesses the `slast` property of the `Row` object. It's equivalent to `Row["slast"]`. You need the latter notation in `fnCheck_Vis()` because you want to access the property *whose name is stored* in `sField`, not the `sField` property.

Comment: Thank you Frédéric, your reply and follow-up are most appreciated.